# Unable to print text from items with 'find_elements_by_xpath'

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, selenium-chromedriver, nameerror

I'm starting web scraping and followed tutorials. Yet in this code I get a "nameError: name 'avail' is not defined". I guess it's really easy, but how could I fix this ? (Error is probably in the for loop at line 15 in avail = i.text())

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/victorfichtner/Downloads/Chromedriver')

    driver.get('https://www.myntra.com/smart-watches/boat/boat-unisex-black-storm-m- 
    smart-watch/13471916/buy')
    a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='pdp-add-to-bag pdp-button pdp-flex 
    pdp-center']")

    for i in a :
    avail = i.text()

    driver.quit()

    print(avail)
```

Comment: if `a` is empty, and nothing is iterated, then the print statement outside the loop doesn't have an assigned variable... Please fix the indentation of your code

Comment: If `a` is empty then `avail` does not get defined.

Comment: You dont need a variable to print it, by the way... `print(i.text())` would "fix the problem"

Answer (score 1):

Things to be noted.

1. `find_elements` return a `list`, where as `find_element` return a single web element.
2. Xpath is brittle.
3. Use explicit waits for dynamic loading.
4. It is `.text` in `Python` not `.text()`

**Sample code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/victorfichtner/Downloads/Chromedriver')

driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get('https://www.myntra.com/smart-watches/boat/boat-unisex-black-storm-m- smart-watch/13471916/buy')

a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'pdp-add-to-bag pdp-button pdp-flex')]")
avail = ""
for i in a :
    avail = i.text

driver.quit()

print(avail)
```

**Output :**

```
ADD TO BAG
```